# Git failed to push some refs due to large file though the large file isn't tracked and not on the local system

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, git-merge

I want to sync my local changes to the GitHub master repo online. I originally had a file over 100 MB but since added it to the `.gitignore` file. I moved the large file to another, untracked non-Git folder.

```bash
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'master/master' by 42 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When I run git push,

```bash
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 216, done.
Counting objects: 100% (215/215), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (185/185), done.
Writing objects: 100% (201/201), 85.26 MiB | 4.67 MiB/s, done.
Total 201 (delta 73), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (73/73), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: warning: File data/SU_COMP_LT.csv is 78.18 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 59a9f7d74f43667d95618d6bc07346491424a287ecab333c99fa78e5714e39da
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/SU_COMP_LT.csv is 117.74 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/path.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/path.git'
```

I tried `git reset file_name` and `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` and the big file isn't tracked. How do I sync the local repo to the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) and [their website](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). Using GitBash,

```bash
$ cd your_local_git_directory
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/your_online_git_directory
$ java -jar C:/path_to_the_bfg_jar_file/bfg-1.13.2.jar --no-blob-protection --delete-files big_file_name.csv
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ git push --force
```

Then finally, I confirmed everything,

```bash
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'master/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `.gitignore` have no effect on items that have previously been tracked.

To fix this run (in **VS Code** you should be able to do this from the console itself or you can use something like **Git Bash**):

```
git reset file_name
```

*In your case `file_name` would be the file that is over 100MB.*

This will unstage the file and keep it but should now ignore it if it is added to the `.gitignore`. Hope that helps

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I also tried `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` and the file isn't even tracked...

Comment: how is this such a difficult problem to solve? were you able to?